# HTML5 canvas drawing not clearing & calibration off

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, drawing

The clear button does not clear the canvas on click. However, when I click back onto the canvas after pressing clear, the canvas itself clears.

Another issue I've been having is the cursor is not the start point of the path.

Here is my code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('doodle-canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var radius = 10;
var dragging = false;

canvas.width = document.getElementById('doodle-canvas').clientWidth;
canvas.height = document.getElementById('doodle-canvas').clientHeight;

context.lineWidth = radius*2;


var clearButton = document.getElementById('doodle-bin');

/* CLEAR CANVAS */
function clearCanvas(){
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

clearButton.addEventListener('click', clearCanvas);



var putPoint = function(e) {
 
 if (dragging) {
  context.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  context.stroke();
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
  context.fill();
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
 }
}

var engage = function(e) {
 dragging = true;
 putPoint(e);
}
var disengage = function() {
 dragging = false;
 context.beginPath();
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', engage);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putPoint);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no issue with the clear button. It does clear the canvas,

and for the cursor issue, use `e.offsetX` and `e.offsetY` instead of `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` respectively.

```js
var clearButton = document.getElementById('doodle-bin');
var canvas = document.getElementById('doodle-canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var radius = 10;
var dragging = false;

canvas.width = document.getElementById('doodle-canvas').clientWidth;
canvas.height = document.getElementById('doodle-canvas').clientHeight;

/* CLEAR CANVAS */
function clearCanvas() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

clearButton.addEventListener('click', clearCanvas);

var putPoint = function (e) {
    if (dragging) {
        context.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
        context.lineWidth = radius * 2;
        context.stroke();
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        context.fill();
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    }
};

var engage = function (e) {
    dragging = true;
    putPoint(e);
};

var disengage = function () {
    dragging = false;
    context.beginPath();
};

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', engage);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putPoint);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage);
```

```css
body{margin:10px 0 0 0;overflow:hidden}canvas{margin-top:5px;border:1px solid #e4e6e8}
```

```html
<button id="doodle-bin">Clear</button>
<canvas id="doodle-canvas" width="635" height="182" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you. The callibration works fine now, however the clear button is still being tricky. This is my html:

`<div id="doodle-tools">
    <div id="equipment">
     <a id="doodle-pencil"></a>
     <a id="doodle-rubber"></a>
     <a id="doodle-bin"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="colors"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
   <canvas id="doodle-canvas"></canvas>`

Comment: which one is your clear button.. `<div class="clear"></div>` or `<a id="doodle-bin"></a>` ?

Comment: <a id="doodle-bin"></a>

Comment: use `button` tag for all the buttons instead of `a` ... `<button id="doodle-bin">clear</button>`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you G